# PHP 7 strpos bug

Tags: php, strpos

When using strpos() to find the following, there seems to be a bug.

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
if (strpos($url,'https')>0) the result is NOT found
if (strpos($url,'https',0)>0) the result is NOT found
if (strpos($url,'ttps')>0) the result is FOUND
```

Why is this happening?
Even though I indicate the starting position of 0, it is not finding it.
Is this a bug or is there something subtle I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: Not a bug, misunderstanding how the function works. See the PHP API for example usage and details. Link is in the answer below.

Comment: It is a normal computing practice for a sequence (e.g. index in an array, position of substring, etc) to start from zero (0). I remember that this concept was taught in the 1st lesson of my course in C

Answer (score 2):

Per the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

> **Returns the position** of [...] the needle [...] note that string **positions start at 0**, and not 1.
> Returns false if the needle was not found

> Warning:
> This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to false. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

You need to check for strpos === false. Otherwise PHP implicitly converts the 0 to false.

Answer (score 1):

The return value 0 means that the substring was found at position 0 in the searched string.

So, the check for > 0 is wrong.

Documentation says:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
> beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
> that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns false if the needle was not found. Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to false. Please read the section on
> Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
> return value of this function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php